# SQLite database not refreshing in iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite, load, refresh

So I got SQLite database working for my app. It loads text values from database, copies it to the array and displays it in Table View.

The first time I got it going i had the values Tuesday, Thursday, Saturday displaying. Then I modified the database using SQLite Manager add-on for firefox (I also used it to create it) by adding new values. However, the new values are not displaying, and even if I delete values like Saturday, the same old "Tuesday, Thursday, Saturday" keeps reappearing. I'm baffled.

Notes:

- I tried restarting Xcode and even the computer lol.
- When I modify database in SQLite Manager, the update time on database file is refreshed in Xcode.
- My database management, just like in the tutorial, happens in AppDelegate.
- In appdelegate: (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions I have this code at beginning

  ```
  routines = nil; // Reset array
  database = nil; // not opened yet
  selStmt = nil; // no compiled statement yet
  updStmt = nil; // no compiled statement yet
  ```

I'm following this tutorial and modifying it on my needs:
http://technologyservants.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=46:shopping-list-an-iphone-sqlite-tutorial

Comment: LOL. Did you try unplugging the cord and plugging it again too? =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably copying the database from the app bundle into the documents directory if it doesn't already exist in the documents directory.

The next time you run your app (with a new db) you check that the db exists in the user's documents directory and then you're probably not copying it again. You're not comparing the versions of the db, you're just checking that a db with that name exists.

If you're in development still, an easy solution is to just clear reset the content and settings of the simulator, which will cause your app to copy the db again.

Comment: Thanks, resetting worked. So the app loads the database once from the directory. But when I update it using my app, not outside source, the database will be updated right (Just in the bundle, not the "directory")?

Comment: Right, when you update your app, the new db is in your app bundle. But the code from that tutorial checks in the Documents directory to see if a db with that name already exists. When it finds the old db still there, it doesn't copy over the new one.

Answer (score 2):

As Firoze stated (I only skimmed the tutorial so forgive me if I'm wrong) on the first load the database is copied from the bundle and into the documents directory. For each launch after that there is no need to copy the database out as it already exists.

If you are working on the simulator and want to change the data so it is reflected live while you work you need to open the database located at

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/<app bundle identifier>/Documents/<database file>
```

The file may not be in that exact location but it gives you an idea of where to start looking around